# Form data taken via Ajax and POSTed to a PHP script for input into DB

Tags: php, ajax, forms, post

This is probably very simple, but I'm really in over my head. Basically, I have a form with one input: email, and a submit button. This was not done by me so I understand very little of it. I tried to look up the .ajax jQuery command, but it still makes no sense.

Basically, here is what I have on the index.php.

The JS and HTML:

```
<!-- Subscription -->
<script>        
    $(function() {
        $('form input.submit').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.returnValue = false;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'subscribe.php',
                data: {email: $('form input[type=email]').val()},
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data == 'successful') {
                        $('#subscribe_status').html('Thanks for subscribing! We will let you know.').slideDown();
                    } else if (data == 'already_subscribed') {
                        $('#subscribe_status').html('This email is already subscribed.').slideDown();
                    } else if (data == 'invalid_email') {
                        $('#subscribe_status').html('This email is invalid.').slideDown();
                    } else {
                        $('#subscribe_status').html('Something went wrong. Please try again.').slideDown(); 
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#subscribe_status').html('Subscription is not available.').slideDown();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>   
<form action="#">
    <input type="email" value="Your e-mail address..." onfocus="value=''" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Notify me" />
</form>
```

Subscribe.php

```
include 'go.php';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$timestamp = date("m/d/y H:i A");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO subscribers (ip, email, timestamp) VALUES (INET_ATON('$ip'), '$email', '$timestamp') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

I basically just keep getting "Something went wrong. Please try again."

Comment: in your subscribe.php put this: "var_dump($_POST);" and see what comes through

Comment: In your success function, the `data` parameter will be whatever your PHP file echo'd. So if you echo nothing on successful data entry (which it looks like might be happening), then the JavaScript will think that something went wrong. Can you confirm that the data is actually being entered into the database?

Comment: No, the data is not going in the database. Am I supposed to have 'echo "successful";' as my last line of my php? EDIT: That didn't work.

Comment: Then the next step is just assuming some dummy value for `$ip` and executing the SQL query by hand. What error message(s) do you get when you do that?

Comment: You should really attach a debugger and look at the response you're getting.  Run it in Chrome and hit F12.  Go to the network tab and look at what the server is telling you.

(Sidenote: I hope this is just test/example code, as it's vulnerable to ... a lot.)

Comment: haha oh boy this was silly. I never entered a an ip field in the mysql database. When I got the database structure correct the script worked just fine. Side note: echo in the end of the php file WAS actually necessary. Otherwise the JS doesn't know if the PHP file did its thing. Although the data still enters the DB. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Subscribe.php` doesn't return anything, so `data` in your JS is always emtpy, hence the last else is always executed.